# Pagination in Blogger Api V3

Tags: api, google-api, blogger, blogspot

how can i get 10 posts and then get the older 10 posts and so on 
i mean pagination 
i need this in blogger API V3

i tried 
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/1309320265504420965/posts?maxResults=10&start-index=1&key=[your-key]

and tried
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/1309320265504420965/posts?maxResults=10&start-index=2&key=[your-key]
but nothing changed

start-index does not seem to be working in V3

even if i changed the value of start-index .. it doesn't change the reply

any ideas ?

Comment: do u get a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

after checking the Blogger API V3 again and again 
i found that , u can find tag named "nextPageToken" and it is a string
u can use this string that contain next page ID and add it to the parameter "pageToken" in the request and u ll get pagination feature work !

Comment: @Atif, www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/BLOG_ID/posts?key=BLOG_API_KEY&pageToken=NEXT_PAGE_TOKEN

Comment: I dont' think there's any "nextPageToken" now in response. Documentations shows that you'll get this in the response of fetching posts from blogID but there's no such key in the response.

Comment: nextPageToken is ok, but how do I know previous page token

Answer (score 0):

**The below format works for me. Try it:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/<blog_ID>/posts?key=<api_key>&maxResults=30&nextPageToken=<nextPageToken here>
```