# How to get the next page results of the blogger API posts/search?

Tags: api, google-api, blogger, google-apis-explorer

I'm making the following request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/(blogId)/posts/search?key=(myKey)&q=(someSearchTerm)
```

and I'm getting 10 items at the result and a `nextPageToken` field.

How can I get the next 10 items with this page token?

**update**

when i add the `nextPageToken` string with the parameter `pageToken` to the url like so:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/(blogId)/posts/search?key=(myKey)&q=(someSearchTerm)&pageToken=(stringOfNextPageToken)
```

nothing happens and i get the same 10 items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pagination in Blogger Api V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751619/pagination-in-blogger-api-v3)

Answer (score 1):

When using:

```
{Google API URL}/posts/?{parameters}&pageToken={nextPageToken}
```

JSON data response contains the next items. Which is the expected behavior, as described in [Pagination in Blogger Api V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751619/pagination-in-blogger-api-v3).

But when using :

```
{Google API URL}/posts/search/?{parameters}&pageToken={nextPageToken}
```

JSON data response contains the same items again. Looks like `pageToken` is ignored by `/posts/search/`.

I opened an [issue in Google API Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/issues/1381).

**Updated :**
In the mean time, I'm using standard Blogger feeds `{Blog URL}/feeds/posts/` and forgot about using the Google API v3.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, it's not a bug, though it needs more clarification, you can refer to this document from Blogger API v3 [here](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/list).

to get the pagination work you need to call the API with maxResults={pageSize} then you will get an extra value in the response 'nextPageToken', you should use the value of this field and pass it with. 'pageToken' **NOT** 'nextPageToken'

```
https://blablabla?maxResults=10&pageToken={VALUE_OF_NEXTPAGETOKEN}
```

when you reach the end of the list you won't get the nextPageToken anymore and it means nothing more to fetch.